# Getting full event text in AWS Cloudformation console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying a CloudFormation template with nested stacks, using 'sam build' and 'sam deploy' from the VSCode terminal.

When a nested stack fails, the errors do not 'bubble up' to the parent stack so I don't see the errors from the child stack in the terminal. An answer to a question I posted earlier in StackOverflow pointed to documentation that this is 'by design' and that if I want to see the errors I should use the AWS CloudFormation console.

Now I'm finding that in the AWS CloudFormation console, in the 'Events' tab of the child stack, long error messages are truncated. The only way I can find to get the entire text of the event is to hover my mouse over the truncated text to get a tooltip with the full event text, which makes it difficult to copy/paste.

Is there a better way to do this? It seems that Amazon's "customer obsession" really hasn't found its way to the CloudFormation product team. I shouldn't have to jump through hoops to get a usable error message that tells me why my stack failed to build. But it seems that I do. Can anyone tell me the appropriate set of hoops in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cloudformation console, find settings:

[image]

Check Wrap Lines. This will display entire error description

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple solution, hidden away. You've just made my day a lot easier.

Comment: Even I found it after several months of usage :). I wish they make wrap lines as default